# How to make a color gradient for turtles in NetLogo 6.2?

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to create a yellow color gradient for the turtles. I have 31 turtle profiles and I would like each of the turtles to be a yellow color. I'm trying more what remains are all in white. And I think I'm complicating the code and the result is not coming out. Has anyone done something similar? If so, could you suggest a way?

```
globals [ AvailablePatch UnassignedProfileCountList ValidHabs MidpointnlColor2 TotalShades2 ]
    
turtles-own [ turtle-profiles-habitat ]

patches-own [ turtle-count habitatcover ]

to setup
  clear-all    
 set ValidHabs [ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 ] 
  
  set UnassignedProfileCountList [ 0 ] 
  repeat 31
      [
        set UnassignedProfileCountList lput 9 UnassignedProfileCountList
  ]
  
  
  (    
    foreach ValidHabs [      
      this-profile ->      
      
      set MidpointnlColor2 yellow
      set TotalShades2 2
      
      
      ask one-of AvailablePatch
              [
                sprout 1
                
                [
                  set turtle-profiles-habitat this-profile
                  
                  
                  set color make-nl-color-shade2 MidpointnlColor2 ValidHabs TotalShades2            
                  
                  set size 1
                ]
                set turtle-count count turtles-here
                set AvailablePatch other AvailablePatch            
      ]
        ]
  )
end


to-report make-nl-color-shade2 [ nl-color shade-value num-shades ]  
  set shade-value min list num-shades max list 0 shade-value
  report scale-color nl-color shade-value num-shades 0 
end
```

Comment: I don't undestand, if you want all the profiles to have another color (so 31 different shades of yellow) or just two different shades, one for the upper half of the profiles and one for the lower half?

Comment: Hi Lena, I would like to have 31 different shades of yellow... is it possible neh? Thanks :)

Comment: Another hint for debugging (for finding errors in you code). All of your turtles turned out white. If you add some lines into the `make-nl-color-shade2` reporter, that `show`s the value of the variables, you can notice that `show shade-value` shows 0 for all turtles. If you print `show max list 0 shade-value`, you can see, that the `max` is surprisingly 0. If you print `list 0 shade-value`, you can see why: it shows [0 [ 1 2 3 ...]]. The only number in there is 0, so `max`  ignores other types of items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can shade the colors using `scale-color color number range1 range2`.
When you want to scale if based on the `ValidHabs`, you want the range to go from the smallest (`min ValidHabs`) to the highest value (`max ValidHabs`) of `ValidHabs`.
For every turtle, you want to have their actual habitat, that is `turtle-profiles-habitat`.

So anywhere in a turtle procedure, you can:

```
set color scale-color yellow turtle-profiles-habitat (min ValidHabs) (max ValidHabs)
```

Comment: Hi Lena, but, ValidHabs and turtle-profiles-habitat is a list and the scale-color command doesn't accept it. That's why I tried using the make-nl-color-shade2 procedure. Do you have any solution to use the scale-color command with list? Thanks for the answers an

Comment: How about you use the `get-profile` reporter from this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70776547/how-to-transform-a-list-where-each-item-is-a-number-from-1-to-31-in-netlogo?
`set color scale-color yellow (get-profile turtle-profiles-habitat) 1 31`

Comment: Hi Lena. Perfect! Solved the problem. Thank you so much again :)