# How to transform a list where each item is a number from 1 to 31 in NetLogo?

Tags: netlogo

I'm having trouble transforming a list in my code below...

The problem: I have a list called:

```
ValidHabs: [[1] [2] [3] [4] [5] [1 2] [1 3] [1 4] [1 5] [2 3] [2 4] [2 5] [3 4] [3 5] [4 5] [1 2 3] [1 2 4] [1 2 5] [1 3 4] [1 3 5] [1 4 5] [2 3 4] [2 3 5] [2 4 5] [3 4 5] [1 2 3 4] [1 2 3 5] [1 2 4 5] [1 3 4 5] [2 3 4 5] [1 2 3 4 5]]
```

And I have a turtle-profiles-habitat variable that appears as one item of ValidHabs list, For example:

```
[1]
[2]
[3]
[4]
[5]
[1 2] and so on
```

I need to turn turtle-profiles-habitat into a number that goes from 1 to 31. For example:

```
profile type 1 is in these habitats: [1]
profile type 2 is in these habitats: [2]
profile type 3 is in these habitats: [3]
profile type 4 is in these habitats: [4]
profile type 5 is in these habitats: [5]
profile type 6 is in these habitats: [1 2]
profile type 7 is in these habitats: [1 3]
profile type 8 is in these habitats: [1 4]
profile type 9 is in these habitats: [1 5]
profile type 10 is in these habitats: [2 3]
profile type 11 is in these habitats: [2 4]
profile type 12 is in these habitats: [2 5]
profile type 13 is in these habitats: [3 4]
profile type 14 is in these habitats: [3 5]
profile type 15 is in these habitats: [4 5]
profile type 16 is in these habitats: [1 2 3]
profile type 17 is in these habitats: [1 2 4]
profile type 18 is in these habitats: [1 2]
profile type 19 is in these habitats: [1 3 4]
profile type 20 is in these habitats: [1 3]
profile type 21 is in these habitats: [1 4]
profile type 22 is in these habitats: [2 3 4]
profile type 23 is in these habitats: [2 3]
profile type 24 is in these habitats: [2 4 5]
profile type 25 is in these habitats: [3 4 5]
profile type 26 is in these habitats: [1 2 3 4]
profile type 27 is in these habitats: [1 3 4]
profile type 28 is in these habitats: [1 2 4 5]
profile type 29 is in these habitats: [1 3]
profile type 30 is in these habitats: [2 3 4 5]
profile type 31 is in these habitats: [1 2 3 4]
```

I need to transform a list to use this information in another part of the code. I tried to create a list (list3) that didn't work very well, that's why it's commented out in code

Could anyone help me tweak my code?

Thanks in advance :)

The code below:

```
globals [  ValidHabs ]  

to setup
  set ValidHabs [ [1] [2] [3] [4] [5] [1 2] [1 3] [1 4] [1 5] [2 3] [2 4] [2 5] [3 4] [3 5] [4 5] [1 2 3] [1 2 4] [1 2 5] [1 3 4] [1 3 5] [1 4 5] [2 3 4] [2 3 5] [2 4 5] [3 4 5] [1 2 3 4] [1 2 3 5] [1 2 4 5] [1 3 4 5] [2 3 4 5] [1 2 3 4 5] ]
  print ( word "ValidHabs: " ValidHabs )
end
```

Comment: this is not reproducible code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `position` command. According to the [NetLogo Manual](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#position) it needs the inputs `item list` and reports the position of the item in the list, starting from 0. That's why you have to add a 1 to it.

An example:

```
globals [ValidHabs]

to go
  set ValidHabs [ [1] [2] [3] [4] [5] [1 2] [1 3] [1 4] ]
  show get-profile [1 2] ;reports 6
end

to-report get-profile [habitats]
  report (position habitats ValidHabs) + 1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very unclear what exactly you want or need, but the first thing that came to my mind is to make a few invisible turtles of some breed with properties. You can then do

```
[profile] of one-of breedx with [profile-number] = 15
```

or something to that effect to get the information you need. you'll have to add the information to these turtles by hand because there is no algorithm for the list you posted (which contains duplicates).

Comment: I managed to solve the problem with the first suggestion. Thank you so much for the answers and suggestions :)